# Ember Getting Started

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm playing the Ember doing the Getting Started tutorial: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/displaying-model-data/ but I got stuck, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Everything was fine until I got to Displaying Model Data, you only has to add:

```
Todos.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return Todos.Todo.find();
  }
});
```

to return all existing todos and replace the static html with handlebars to make it dynamic:

```
<ul id="todo-list">
  {{#each controller}}
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
      <label>{{title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

And this is the result:
[image]

As I said, it worked fine before until this point. Code [right here](http://jsbin.com/atinup/3/edit).

Comment: the ember file you're referencing in the fiddle isn't reachable.  the fiddle fails with errors for me as a result.

Comment: @ben336 I the tutorial I have:
js/app.js
js/application.js
js/router.js
models/store.js
models/todo.js

Should I put it all together in the javascript?

Anyways, I think the point really is why is not working locally?

Comment: I don't know why its not working locally, just pointing out that including a fiddle is unhelpful if it does not contain a working reference to the library you're using :)

Comment: honest question, is your handlebars template inside of a `script` tag?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe No, I didn't! Now it is working fine locally :) BUT in jsbin is showing nothing. I'm using the same html the only that is different are the js references. I have jquery, handlebars, ember and ember-data. Also, I put all the js together. I have no idea what am I doing wrong? Thank you. http://jsbin.com/atinup/3/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed your app a little. Before you had two instances of `Ember.Application` called `App` and `Todo` operating in the same scope. By default, an Ember App uses the `body` element as the `rootElement` (where your app is going to render), so your apps were colliding.

If you *really* need two apps running on the same page, use [`Application#rootElement`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#property_rootElement) to inform the selector of the element you want the apps to render. I would say you should avoid using the `body` as `rootElement` when you have multiple applications sharing the same document (if that's what you wanted).

As per your image, I don't think you need two apps, and I'm assuming you just want the To Do app, so I have removed `App`, leaving only `Todo` (see fixed [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ihetob/2/edit)).

I have noticed that all your HTML was static and you were not using Handlebars at all, as well as some incorrect js references which have been fixed.

Instead of doing the following:

```
  <section id="main">
    <ul id="todo-list">
      <li class="completed">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        <label>Learn Ember.js</label><button class="destroy"></button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        <label>...</label><button class="destroy"></button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        <label>Profit!</label><button class="destroy"></button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  <!-- more stuff-->
```

Use Handlebars, as it provides the [`{{each}}`](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/) helper, which allows you do iterate through your collection like this:

```
    <ul id="todo-list">
    {{#each filteredTodos itemController="todo"}}
      <li {{bindAttr class="isCompleted:completed isEditing:editing"}}>
        {{#if isEditing}}
          {{view Todos.EditTodoView todoBinding="this"}}
        {{else}}
          {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="isCompleted" class="toggle"}}
            <label {{action "editTodo" on="doubleClick"}}>{{title}}</label>
            <button {{action "removeTodo"}} class="destroy"></button>
        {{/if}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

This will create a `li` element *for each* model in your controller (in this case, from the computed `filteredTodos`).

I strongly recommend you to dive into the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/) to learn more about ember.